# After user login, when back is pressed login.html displayed

Tags: django

I have a login form. When login button is pressed user's homepage is displayed. But pressing browser's back button takes control back to login form. 
I am using django development server.

I have tried inserting meta tags to prevent cache and django @no-cache

But it doesnt work out

Comment: Can you able to find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

The default django login page can be viewed when logged in. You could decorate the login view function and redirect the user if already logged in.

Answer (score -1):

```
    response = <the_way_you_create_response> (ie direct_to_template, HttpResponse)
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store'
    return response
```

and of course you need to check request.user.is_authenticated()  in the view (and do the redirect if value is True)

Comment: The default django login page is displayed, even when logged in. This is not a cache issue.

Comment: Maybe, but even if the login view will be decorated, pressing browser's back button will show login page, because it will be cached (and request won't be re-send). Your answer resolves only problem with direct entry.

Answer (score -2):

In your login page you need to check if a users session exists and if it does then you should redirect the user to his homepage.

However, this can't be done with a HTML page so you need to use some kinda server side scripting language(PHP, ASP, JSP Etc) for your login page.

Comment: Please update your answer to show how this problem can be solved in Django. A generic answer as yours is not helpful. Will upvote if sufficient.